# Android 2.2 api level 8 in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo

I want to write a simple app for an android 2.2 device. (Api 8)

When I create a new project in android studio the minium sdk I can select is api 9, android 2.3.

How do I target an older version?

Comment: Download the version from the SDK manager. This is a looooooooooooong way back to support though. Any reason?

Comment: I downloaded it, but I still cant select android 2.2 when I create a new project...

Comment: Maybe Android Studio is telling you it isn't worth supporting a 6+ year old version that has 0.1% distribution :P Is there a purpose to supporting back that far?

Comment: I have an 'entourage edge' which only supports android 2.2, that 0.1% is important if its me ;)

Comment: There you go, always a reason, just wanted to know what it was :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not get anything specific also remotely from developing for Android 2.2.
No new or even very few old devices exist for Android 2.2.

But if you are thinking to install Android 2.2 on any Raspberry Pi style devices, that changes everything.

You need to get an Android Studio older than 2.0 version from this link 
[Android Studio Canary Channel Downloads for all versions](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary)

Comment: I downloaded an old version (1.5) This allow me to select anrdoid 2.2 but when I create the new project I get an error: ` Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1] /home/sam/AndroidStudioProjects/EdgeHello/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/24.2.1/AndroidManifest.xml
   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage`

Comment: Oh! This one, it is due to the material design library get rid of the appcompat support library and you are good to go.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Paste the code from your gradle file into your question.